# Unable to Import BACPAC files to SSMS2017

Tags: ssms

I'm trying to import .BACPAC file to Sql server management studio and i'm facing the below error.

Kindly note I'm having the latest version "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   14.0.17289.0"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have Installed SMMS2018. It solves the BACPAC Import problem.